# Drawing a tree structure in android

Tags: tree, android

I have to design layout dynamically as below [image]
I tried using View-Group ,but unable to draw respective connected lines properly.

Comment: Remark: you should resize your image (to much height).

Comment: i am also looking for this because i want to make a family tree like app.i am getting expandable list view when i search for this.